# crystal report viewer fill depend on browse file

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, crystal-reports

I have a form where you can browse a file, so when i select the MS access file where the database contain, there is a button "Show Report" and i want to fill the next form which is Crytal Report Viewer, depend on what file is being browse, Can someone help me here? im having a big trouble here, I look at SAP.COM also at MICROSOFT Visual Studio forums but nobody gets the answer. heres my code in my **BROWSE BUTTON**:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
```

and in my **SHOW REPORT BUTTON**:

```
Form2.ShowDialog()
    Form2.Dispose()
```

Comment: you do know you have to do more than get the name of the Access DB right?  where is that code?

Comment: possible duplicate of equally unclear [Open file dialog sends to Crystal report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346668/open-file-dialog-sends-to-crystal-report)

Comment: @Plutonix thats my account too.

Comment: @Plutonix Code of what?

Comment: do you really think all you have to do is point to a access file and a  report will magically launch?

Comment: @Plutonix I dont have any code other than that, because i want to launch Access Db, when i browse it, then display its path in the textbox, then click the SHOW REPORT button to view it to the Crystal Report Viewer form.

Comment: thats not what a FileDialog does, thats not how Access works, thats not what buttons do and thats not how CR works, so good luck.